# Why would I use MockWebServer instead of WireMock?

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock, mockwebserver

Every time when I need to mock some http requests my first choise is WireMock (which is actually standard for that I think), but today I discovered some alternative tool - MockWebServer.

What are pros and cons of [WireMock](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock) vs [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)?

Answer (score 20):

Basically `MockWebServer` was invented to run smoothly on Android devices. There were several problems with `WireMock` setup on Android and thats why `MockWebServer` was invented.

If you use mocking on your backend though then I recommend `WireMock` since it's more feature rich.

There is nice article on the topic here:

https://handstandsam.com/2016/01/30/running-wiremock-on-android/

especially *My recommendation* section